# How to check an object exist or not in Gsp?

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

```
<g:each in="${clientTripInstance?.startPointJob?.passengerActivities}" status="i" var="startPassengerActivity">
     <g:if test = "${startPassengerActivity?.passengerCount > 1}">
         <p> ${startPassengerActivity?.activity}  ${startPassengerActivity?.passengerRole?.displayName} (${startPassengerActivity?.passengerCount})
     </p>
     </g:if>
     <g:else>
       <p> ${startPassengerActivity?.activity}  ${startPassengerActivity?.passengerRole?.displayName}
          </p>
     </g:else>
</g:each>
```

this code works fine when clientTripInstance?.startPointJob?.passengerActivities is exist.. there are some case when clientTripInstance?.startPointJob?.passengerActivities is not exist... so how to check is not exist ? i dont want to display anything if its not exist..

the domain class are

```
   class Trip {
            String notes
           List<PointJob> pointJobs = new ArrayList<PointJob>()
   }

   class PointJob {
       Point point
   List<PassengerActivity> passengerActivities = new ArrayList<PassengerActivity>();
   }


  class PassengerActivity {
    PassengerRole passengerRole;
    String activity;
    int passengerCount;

static constraints = {
    passengerRole()
    activity()
    passengerCount(nullable:true)
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just wrap it all in another test to ensure the list isn't null or empty?

```
<g:if test="${clientTripInstance?.startPointJob?.passengerActivities}">
  <g:each in="${clientTripInstance?.startPointJob?.passengerActivities}" status="i" var="startPassengerActivity">
    <g:if test = "${startPassengerActivity?.passengerCount > 1}">
      <p>
        ${startPassengerActivity?.activity}  ${startPassengerActivity?.passengerRole?.displayName} (${startPassengerActivity?.passengerCount})
      </p>
    </g:if>
    <g:else>
      <p>
        ${startPassengerActivity?.activity}  ${startPassengerActivity?.passengerRole?.displayName}
      </p>
    </g:else>
  </g:each>
</g:if>
```

Comment: What happens when you do this? If `clientTripInstance?.startPointJob?.passengerActivities` is null, it shouldn't be displaying anything.

Comment: Just a note on this answer, the second set of safe navigation operators ( ?. ) are redundant .  If safe navigation does not fail in the "if" tag, then obviously all of the objects in the path of "clientTripInstance?.startPointJob?.passengerActivities" exist.